# Laravel how to show video by it's id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So first of all I just started to work with laravel and overall with php. Right now I'm facing a problem where I don't know how to display specific video from my database. My User model:

```
class User extends Model implements Authenticatable{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
    public function videos() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Video');
    }
}
```

My Video model:

```
class Video extends Model{
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Everything goes well when I loop through my videos to display them all in dashboard:

```
<div class="row" id="features">
        @foreach($videos as $video)
            <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title video_name">{{ $video->video_name }}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <iframe width="320" height="250"
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ $video->video_url  }}" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen">
                    </iframe>
                    <div class="info">
                    <p>Posted by {{ $video->user->first_name }} on {{ $video->created_at }}</p>
                        <hr class="postInfo">
                    </div>

                    <p>{{ $video->description }} </p>
                    <a href="{{ route('view.video', [$video->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Continue to video</a>
                </div>
            </div>
         @endforeach
    </div>
```

But At this point:

```
<a href="{{ route('view.video', [$video->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Continue to video</a>
```

I open new route which is (http://localhost:8000/video/11/view) and in this case  I want to display video where ID 11 is equal to my video_url

videos table code:

```
public function up(){
        Schema::create('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->text('video_name');
            $table->text('video_url');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('user_id');
        });
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/video/{video_id}/view', [
    'uses' => 'SignInController@ViewVideo',
    'as' => 'view.video']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the route to following..

```
Route::get('/video/{video}/view', [
 'uses' => 'SignInController@ViewVideo',
  'as' => 'view.video']);
```

In Controller..

```
public function ViewVideo(Video $video){
  //any authorization logic...
  return view('whatever',compact('video'));
}
```

Comment: It worked <3 such a simple solution, thank you a lot ! :)

Answer (score 0):

As of Laravel 5.2 there is a thing called `Implicit Route Model Binding` You can read the docs about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding).

So in your example. You can change your route like this:

```php
Route::get('/video/{video}/view', [
    'uses' => 'SignInController@ViewVideo',
    'as' => 'view.video'
]);
```

And in your `Video` controller's view method:

```php
public functin view(App\Video $video) {
    // Your logic
}
```